# Elasticsearch 5.4 - filter by term if the term exists and don't filter when term is not present

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm searching on multiple types. One of the types returned has a field called my_field. The other types returned do not have that field. I want all results where the term does not exist and only the results where the field has the value True when the term does exist.

It would be great if the filter on my_field didn't contribute to the query score and only filtered.

This is as close as I got. I will self-flagellate for 1 hour if you help me please.

(Don't use this it is wrong!)

```
body = {
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': {
                'multi_match': {
                    'query': 'pangolin',
                    'fields': ['_all', '_partials']
                }
            },
            "should": {
                "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "my_field"
                    }
                }
            },
            "should": {
                'term': {
                    'my_field': True
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note the above does not work because I have 2 shoulds after a must in a bool query context. See docs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to be what I need.
Documents must match on 'pangolin' and documents are filtered on 2 shoulds. Only 1 of the shoulds needs to match.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-bool-query.html (see keywords: filter and should).

```
body = {
    "query": {
        'bool': {
            'must': {
                'multi_match': {
                    'query': 'pangolin',
                    'fields': ['_all', '_partials']
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [{
                            "term": {
                                "my_field": True
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "must_not": {
                                    "exists": {
                                        "field": "my_field"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$ curl -XPOST localhost:9200/type1,type2/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "my_field": true
          }
        },
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "not_missing": {
                "field": "type2.my_field"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Let me know if this works. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you will check out first in morning.